# Changer the properties value

Tags: c#, properties

I'm using a dataset, the ConnectionString is stored in the Project Properties.
I tried to edit the value of the ConnectionString, but I get the Message that it's read only!

I need to modify the ConnectionString, because I have to change it when my Application is deployed to the Clients (need to change user and password).

So how can I modify the ConnectionString?

Comment: put it in your app.config

Comment: don't use properties. Use Web.config / App.Config

Comment: Where in the project properties it is stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in your app.config (of course this could be improved or you could put the entire ConnectionString into the app.config like Karl Anderson mentioned) and don´t forget to Reference System.Configuration

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="dbServer" value="server"/>
   <add key="dbName" value="mydb"/>
   <add key="integratedSecurity" value="true"/>
   <add key="user" value=""/>
   <add key="pwd" value=""/>
</appSettings>
```

and in C#

```
public string GetConnectionString()
{
    var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    builder.DataSource = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbServer"];
    builder.InitialCatalog = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbName"];
    builder.IntegratedSecurtiy = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["integratedSecurity"]);

    string user = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["user"];
    string pwd = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pwd"]
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user))
    {
       builder.UserId = user;
       builder.Password = YourCryptoProvider.Decrypt(pwd);
    }
    return builder.ToString()
}
```

Comment: Good thank's that help, but here I have a problem, that mydataset (generated by the VS) is using the properties!!

Comment: can you please update the question with your code, so I can have a look at it

Comment: Here´s a [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.dataset.aspx) that shows how to create a DataSet with a GetConnectionString-Method

Comment: The code is like this this._connection.ConnectionString = global::MiniGestionStock.Properties.Settings.Default.TestDataConnectionString; so when you modify the application Properties It sad that it's read only because it's made with the application,I'm using linq also and I did not find how to update the connection string

Comment: Just replace the TestDataConnectionString with the Output of the GetConnectionStringProperty

Answer (score 0):

Use the `connectionStrings` section of web.config, like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=YourComputer\sqlexpress;Initial 
         Catalog=YourDatabase;User ID=YourUserName;Password=YourPassword"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Then you can read the value in your code, like this:

```
Configuration rootWebConfig = Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/MyWebSiteRoot");
ConnectionStringSettings connString;

// Are there any connection string values in web.config?
if (rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Count > 0)
{
    // Find the particular connection string we want by name
    connString = rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"];

// Does the connection string exist in web.config?
if (connString != null)
{
    // Yes, so use it here
else
{
    // No, so generate error or alert user or whatever here
}
```